# How to configure the default app to open tel: links in MacOS X?

Tags: macos, html

When clicking `tel:` links in Safari, such as:

```
<a href="tel:+3361234567890">call</a>
```

the FaceTime app opens. **How can I configure it to open Skype instead?**

Comment: https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change it using a utility called 
[RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) - freeware - which installs as a Control Panel. It's old but still works right up to El Capitan [I've not tested on Sierra but see no real reason it shouldn't still work.]

Look for 'tel' in the URLs list & change...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm surprised this tool doesn't belong to MacOS though, or that Safari doesn't provide an explicit setting for this...

Comment: Yeah , strangely it's never been in the OS itself, not as far back as I can recall... which is System 6.0.6 The last browser to be able to do it, iirc, was Internet Explorer for Mac, back in Mac OS 9. RCDefaultFolder has been the go-to app for this since about 2004.

Comment: Works on Sierra 10.12.

Answer (score 20):

You can change this without an extra app via the preferences in FaceTime.
On the Setting tab change the last entry "Default for calls" to Skype.
At least this way works for Skype for Business.

Comment: Alas no more. That option isn't there on my FaceTime 4 on High Sierra

Comment: The option is available in Catalina.

Comment: + works in Catalina, no additional software needed. Thanks.

Comment: Confirm that it works in Big Sur. Actually I was looking for a manner to revert it back to the default setting after installing Skype. The default setting, which is FaceTime, allows integration with your iPhone, enabling your Mac to take or make phone calls.

Comment: +1 should be accepted answer

Comment: I don't even see Settings available. I haven't tried logging into FaceTime. If one needs to log in to FaceTime in order to stop having tel links open FaceTime, that's ridiculous.

Comment: Yep, I _did_ need to log into FaceTime to even get access to FaceTime Settings to be able to see that "Default for calls" is already set to "Brave Browser.app", but my challenge now is to figure out how to make Mac actually open Google Voice in Brave for `tel:` links. Apple always needs to make everything mysterious and difficult if not impossible.

Answer (score 5):

That FaceTime setting is still available on Mojave.

FaceTime/ Preferences/ Settings/ 'Default for calls' *popup list*

Answer (score 1):

None of these work very well if you want to use non-native apps.  For example, in Chrome, clicking on a tel: link will allow you to forward the call to your phone with a single click dial.

The only good workaround I've found for links I create is to preface the number with https://ctrlq.org/call/1234567890 to call 123-456-7890.  This will open all links in your default browser.  So if you use Chrome or Ffox it will fwd to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still searching this, the feature returned for macOS Monterrey - https://support.apple.com/guide/facetime/change-general-settings-fctm35545/mac

Facetime preferences allow the user to change their default (app) for calls.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answer as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Instead please quote the most important parts and provide the link for reference only.